# NSCollectionView with CoreData

Tags: swift, macos, core-data, nsarraycontroller, nscollectionview

I just tried to create my first OSX-Application with swift. For my Project I need a CollectionView which works with CoreData. I build up my App along the lines of this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5LtGt-B94No).

The only difference between the tutorial and my project is that, I'm using CoreData to load the data for my Object.

I created an entry an then Xcode throws this error:

> 2015-12-29 22:29:46.105 toRep_Management[11088:4844788] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity Notice is not key value coding-compliant for the key "dateText".'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff96614ae2 __exceptionPreprocess + 178
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8d9cff7e objc_exception_throw + 48
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff96614679 -[NSException raise] + 9
>       3   CoreData                            0x00007fff9a54ad91 -[NSManagedObject valueForUndefinedKey:] + 289
>       4   Foundation                          0x00007fff8d5229f0 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKeyPath:] + 272
>       5   AppKit                              0x00007fff986393a0 -[NSBinder valueForBinding:resolveMarkersToPlaceholders:] + 164
>       6   AppKit                              0x00007fff9863c936 -[NSValueBinder _adjustObject:mode:observedController:observedKeyPath:context:editableState:adjustState:] + 305
>       7   AppKit                              0x00007fff9863c775 -[NSValueBinder _observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:context:] + 296
>       8   AppKit                              0x00007fff986dcec3 -[NSTextValueBinder _observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:context:] + 43
>       9   Foundation                          0x00007fff8d528a53 NSKeyValueNotifyObserver + 379
>       10  Foundation                          0x00007fff8d534c23 NSKeyValueDidChange + 457
>       11  Foundation                          0x00007fff8d51dba4 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKey:key:key:usingBlock:] + 1148
>       12  Foundation                          0x00007fff8d579c91 _NSSetObjectValueAndNotify + 274
>       13  AppKit                              0x00007fff98893c6c -[NSCollectionView newItemForRepresentedObject:] + 228
>       14  AppKit                              0x00007fff98893736 -[NSCollectionView _getItemsToDisplay] + 1209
>       15  AppKit                              0x00007fff9889317a -[NSCollectionView setContent:] + 318
>       16  AppKit                              0x00007fff98893005 -[NSCollectionViewBinder _updateContent] + 93
>       17  AppKit                              0x00007fff98892f31 -[NSCollectionViewBinder _observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:context:] + 84
>       18  Foundation                          0x00007fff8d528a53 NSKeyValueNotifyObserver + 379
>       19  Foundation                          0x00007fff8d532d7a -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _notifyObserversForKeyPath:change:] + 1127
>       20  AppKit                              0x00007fff986307d8 -[NSController _notifyObserversForKeyPath:change:] + 206
>       21  AppKit                              0x00007fff9868d3e3 -[NSArrayController didChangeValuesForArrangedKeys:objectKeys:indexKeys:] + 54
>       22  AppKit                              0x00007fff9884bcb5 -[NSArrayController _insertObject:atArrangedObjectIndex:objectHandler:] + 514
>       23  AppKit                              0x00007fff9884b8e5 -[NSArrayController addObject:] + 153
>       24  toRep_Management                    0x000000010000bb8d _TFC16toRep_Management16NoticeController12awakeFromNibfS0_FT_T_ + 1661
>       25  toRep_Management                    0x000000010000bdc2 _TToFC16toRep_Management16NoticeController12awakeFromNibfS0_FT_T_ + 34
>       26  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9651433f -[NSSet makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 223
>       27  AppKit                              0x00007fff98501ee4 -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:options:topLevelObjects:] + 1192
>       28  AppKit                              0x00007fff986c580a -[NSNib _instantiateNibWithExternalNameTable:options:] + 677
>       29  AppKit                              0x00007fff986c545a -[NSNib _instantiateWithOwner:options:topLevelObjects:] + 143
>       30  AppKit                              0x00007fff98c4167a -[NSStoryboard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:] + 181
>       31  AppKit                              0x00007fff984da34e NSApplicationMain + 710
>       32  toRep_Management                    0x000000010000e597 main + 87
>       33  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff94ebd5ad start + 1
>       34  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Here is my Code for my NoticeController:

```
@IBOutlet weak var noticeArrayController: NSArrayController!

//CoreData
let context = (NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
let fetchRequestForNotice = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Notice")

var notices: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

override func awakeFromNib() {

    var dataNotices = [Notice]()

    do {
        dataNotices = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequestForNotice) as! [Notice]
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    for var i = 0; i < dataNotices.count; i++ {
        notices.addObject(dataNotices[i])
    }

    for var i = 0; i < notices.count; i++ {

        let newNotice = NoticeObject()

        newNotice.image = NSImage()
        newNotice.title = notices[i].title!
        newNotice.dateText = "iein Datum"

        self.noticeArrayController.addObject(newNotice) // THREAD 1: SIGNAL SIGBART

    }

}
```

And here for my NoticeObject:

```
class NoticeObject: NSObject {

var image: NSImage = NSImage()
var title: String = ""
var dateText: String = "" }
```

Can You help me?

Comment: In the data model editor, check that you have specified the correct class for the Notice entity.

Comment: Remove the class noticeArrayController and use an arraycontroller in entity mode.

Comment: thanks this works for me!